# Test fails with webkit, passes with selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, mongoid, capybara-webkit

```
  it 'allows a new user to sign up', :js do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Sign up'
    old_count = User.all.size
    within '#userModal' do
      fill_in 'user[name]', with: 'some'
      fill_in 'user[email]', with: 'some@test.com'
      fill_in 'user[password]', with: '123123123'
      fill_in 'user[password_confirmation]', with: '123123123'
      d=find('input[type=submit]')
      p d
      p d.class
      d.click
      User.all.size.should == old_count + 1
    end
  end
```

This way works, fails when removing driver selection.

With selenium I get in log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-29 00:51:36 -0500
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
```

While this does not happen with Webkit.

My question is how to find the cause for this behaviour?

Comment: I'm seeing an inconsistency between webkit and selenium as well, though my issue is focused around js validation messages.  Our CI is fully headless though so I can't enable selenium only for this test, need to figure out the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and with a very similar test (testing modals). Were you by any chance testing a Foundation modal?

Comment: I don't remember I think it was a bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, most of my tests that failed when using webkit and passed with selenium, failed due to a race condition. The reason they passed with selenium is that selenium is a lot slower (up to 5 times slower) than webkit.

But I could fix most of my test with webkit by adding a `wait_for_ajax` after sending my requests as described here: [Wait for Ajax with Capybara](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara)

Hope this helps, even though your question is already a year old

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if related, but I did figure out the inconsistency I saw between `selenium` and `webkit`.  It appears that at times, javascript validation was not being triggered in capybara-webkit, whereas it was reliable in `selenium` whether I was using `chrome` or `firefox`.

Here's the snippet:

```
# reliably trigger validation in webkit for client_side_validations
if webkit?
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('form[data-validate]').validate() }
end
```

[My gist explains the rest.](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/5971508)

Another tidbit for people having problems with validations and modals, we found out that we needed to initialize the validators when the elements became visible.

```
$('#invite_modal').on 'shown.bs.modal', ->
  $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate()
```

Comment: hmm, I don't think so, I am not using any validations.

Comment: Sorry juanpastas, I feel your pain.  It took me almost two days to narrow down the ~1 line of code to get my CI running again!